# ASP.net C# enabling and disabling required field validator through javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, file-upload, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using an input type "file" control in asp.net C# web page. The scenario is, when I try to browse any file using this file upload control, a textbox becomes visible and the required field validator gets enabled that controls this textbox. Also there is an input type button that reset the file in the control and text in the textbox to null. I also want to disable this required field validator on reset button click, but I am unable to do so.

I could have used aspx button control to reset the data and disable the required field validator, but this is causing loss of other information on the page. That is why I tried doing this using javascript.

I tried using a code from internet for the same. Here is my design and code:

```
<input ID="FileUploadDownload" type="file" name="file" runat="server" class="cssfileupload" />
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="btnClearAttachment" onclick="clearFileUploadDownload()" class="resetMe"/>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDownloadText" runat="server" placeholder="Type Download File Text" ontextchanged="TextBoxDownloadText_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>    
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText" ValidationGroup="A" ControlToValidate="TextBoxDownloadText" runat="server" CssClass="validator" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

The onchange event of fileupload control is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFile(e) {

    var file_list = e.target.files;

    for (var i = 0, file; file = file_list[i]; i++) {            
        var sFileName = file.name;
        var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1].toLowerCase();
        var iFileSize = file.size;
        var iConvert = (file.size / 10485760).toFixed(2);


        if ((sFileExtension === "pdf" || sFileExtension === "png" || sFileExtension === "jpg" || sFileExtension === "gif")) 
        {      

            //...............Enable validator..................
            var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText.ClientID%>');
            validatorObject.enabled = true;
            validatorObject.isvalid = true;
            ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validatorObject);
            document.getElementById("TextBoxDownloadText").style.border = '1px solid red';
        }

    }
}

function clearFileUploadDownload() {

            $("#FileUploadDownload").val("");
            $('#<%=TextBoxDownloadText.ClientID%>').val("");

            //...............disable validator..................
            var validatorObject = document.getElementById('<%=RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText.ClientID%>');
            validatorObject.enabled = false;
            validatorObject.isvalid = false;
            ValidatorUpdateDisplay(validatorObject);
            document.getElementById("TextBoxDownloadText").style.border = '1px solid green';
}
</script>
```

In the page load event, I have disabled the required field validator:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText.Enabled = false;
        }
 }
```

Onchange event of file upload control enables required validator but on click event of reset button, the validator is not getting disbaled.

Kindly help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var valName = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText.ClientID%>");
        ValidatorEnable(valName, true);
```

to enable and

```
var valName = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidatorTextBoxDownloadText.ClientID%>");
        ValidatorEnable(valName, false);
```

to disable

Comment: I have tried this also, but it is not working. Enabling is working but unable to disable it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I do not find any error. Enable is working but disable is not working.

Comment: I am extremely sorry if I have missed something. But I do not know how to find error in console. Did you mean any kind of exception handling or using Response.Write(). In any case kindly specify.

Comment: hit F12 on your browser, developers tool will be opened go to console and see the error

Comment: Thank you so much for assistance. I did the way you said. It is displaying:-   ReferenceError: approveletter is not defined; 
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Where did you use approveletter? and why?